# node express with orm2 & separated model files

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, express, node-orm2

I am using node & express (framework for node).
I wan't to use the node-orm2 framework for node for communicating with my MySQL database. To keep a nice structure I want to split up my models in separated files. I've been using the documentation on github but somehow I can't make it work.

app.js:

```
app.use(orm.express("mysql://********:********@localhost/*********",
{
    define: function(db, models){
        db.load('./models', function(err){
            models.movie = db.models.Movie;
        });
    }
}));
```

models.js:

```
module.exports = function (db, fn) {
    db.load("movie", function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return fn(err);
        }
    });
//etc
return fn();
};
```

movie.js:

```
module.exports = function (db, fn) {
    db.define('movie', {
        id          : { type: "number" },
        title       : { type: "text" },
        year        : { type: "number" },
        rating      : { type: "number" },
        description : { type: "text" }
    }, {
        methods : {

        }
    });

    return fn();
};
```

Comment: Did you solve  your problem?  I have been working in node-orm2 for three months now and it could help - if this is still open

Comment: [github answer](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2/issues/458#)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Copied help from [github](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2/issues/458#) issue tracker (from [lastmove](https://github.com/lastMove)):**

I am using the built in express middleware.
It works fine for me.
I have a folder Model.
With one file par model.
Example the user model:
user.js

```
module.exports = function(db, cb)
{
    var User = db.define('user', {
              userName : String,
              password : String,
              mail : String,
              mark : Number,
              lastAlertSent : Date,
              subscriptionDate : Date,
              lastAction : Date,
              specialUser : Boolean,
              uuid  : String
              },
              {
         validations:
                 {
                  userName : [orm.enforce.required(error.errorStr(error.missingRequiredField, "userName missing")), orm.enforce.unique({ ignoreCase: true },  error.errorStr(error.usernameAlreadyUsed, "userName already used")), orm.enforce.ranges.length(3, undefined, error.errorStr(error.usernameTooShort, "userName too shoty"))], 
...
```

And in the Models folder i have an index.js
In this file i define the relations betweens my models, and I load my models.

File:
models/index.js

```
checkError = function(cb, err)
{
    if (err)
        return cb(err);
    return cb();
}

module.exports = function(db, cb)
{
    db.load("./user.js", function (err) {checkError(cb, err)});
    db.load("./alert.js", function (err) {checkError(cb, err)});
    db.load("./comment.js", function (err) {checkError(cb, err)});
    db.load("./metropole.js", function (err) {checkError(cb, err)});
    db.load("./period.js", function (err) {checkError(cb, err)});
    db.load("./stop.js", function (err) {checkError(cb, err)});
    db.load("./line.js", function (err) {checkError(cb, err)});
    db.load("./types.js", function (err) {checkError(cb, err)});
    db.load("./historique.js", function(err) {checkError(cb, err)});

    var User = db.models.user;
    var Alert = db.models.alert;
    var Comment = db.models.comment;
    var Metropole = db.models.metropole;
    var Stop = db.models.stop;
    var Line = db.models.line;
    var Period = db.models.period;
    var Types = db.models.types;
    var Hist = db.models.historique;

    Alert.hasOne("stop", Stop, {reverse : "alerts"});
    Alert.hasOne("line", Line, {reverse : "alerts"});
```

and after all in my Express initialization i add this:

```
app.use(orm.express(opts, {
    define: function (db, models, next) {
            db.load("./models/models", function (err2)
        {
            if (err2)   
                throw err2;
            db.sync();
        })
        next();
    }
```